domPDF render takes too long to convert as pdf
Heading ##// Render the HTML as PDF
$pdf->render();
This rendering takes huge time to convert.
Though my file is huge it is taking 30mins to generate, is there any other way to generate faster, I searched a lot, there is no proper result.

If you are render images check the image paths and Ex :{{ asset('assests/img/qr.png') }} use public_path instead of asset Ex : {{ public_path('assests/img/qr.png') }}

Thanks man. I have solved this issue with decreasing img size and splited the pdf into smaller parts and finally merged that now its ok.
